# getApplicationContext() in a singleton class via android?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-context

hola mates i have some code here, but i don't quite understand it's logic. it's
a singleton class that will eventually hold an ArrayList of crimes. i'm going to look up tutorials on singleton so i don't have to bug all of ya, but i still don't understand the concept of 'context' in android, which is throwing me off now e.g.

```
public class CrimeLab 
{
 private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;

 private context mAppContext;

 private CrimeLab(Context mAppContext)
 {
 this.mAppContext = mAppContext;
 }

 public static CrimeLab get(Context c)
 {
 if(sCrimeLab == null){

 sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(C.getApplicationContext()); 

 }
 return sCrimeLab;
 }
}
```

in an activity i call 'mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes(); which will hold the crimes in a listView for a fragmenti know i'm passing the current activity into the CrimeLab singleton class, but what is the purpose of that exactly? it may be a vague question, especially w/out the rest of the code, but just looking at this what do you all infer?

Comment: i just did @AndyTurner

Answer (score -1):

Context is "where you are" in the app. It's used to get environment-specific information, and gets passed around often to supply an information that might be needed. In you're case it's likely the Activity in which this code is being run. Some more info can be found on the Android reference page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: but why exactly am i passing the activity into the singleton?

Comment: I can't say if you strictly "need" to pass it in, but it doesn't hurt. That way if any of Android's background processes or library methods need access to some environment variable, they have it. Not to mention if later on you need access to something specific to the activity, it's already there.